# Can't adjust text wrapping around SVG img

Tags: css

I'm trying to wrap an IMG inside a span, so its parent DIV would have a width of this img + the span.

```css
.mainDiv {
    height: max-content;
    width: max-content;
    border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
    padding: 5px;
}

/*
.mainText {
    display: flex;
}*/

.mainImg {
    float: left;
    max-width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span class="mainText">
    <img src="https://testfabric.net/icons/document.svg" class="mainImg"/>
    line_1<br>
    line_2
  </span>
</div>
```

If I use flex for the span, it breaks the line after the IMG.

If I don't - 'width: max-content' for the parent DIV is not working. Also the text doesn't wrap the IMG.

[image]

The third pic - what I'm extecting to have.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: the common advise is to use 'float: left' for the IMG. As you see - it's not working here.

UPD: the error replicates only when I insert a SVG as IMG. If a JPG is used, it works fine (without flex)

Comment: Cannot replicate. Demo without flex and with image floated - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOdJEGX

Comment: @Paulie_D the problem was - I use a SVG picture. it breaks the line. Simple pics do not

Comment: Then you'll have to demonstrate with the actual svg

Comment: @Paulie_D original snippet updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the `viewbox` of the SVG, it adds an extra `16px` `width`.
We have to decrease that, and adjust the `width` and the `padding-right`, like so:

```css
.mainDiv {
  height: max-content;
  width: max-content;
  border: 1px solid #bebdbd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.mainImg {
  float: left;
  max-width: 14px;
  padding-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainDiv">
  <span class="mainText">
    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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" class="mainImg"/>
    line_1<br>
    line_2
  </span>
</div>
```

The SVG data is the following:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   data-name="Layer 1"
   viewBox="0 0 44 56"
   id="document"
   version="1.1"
   sodipodi:docname="document-mod.svg"
   width="44"
   height="56"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview4"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#000000"
     borderopacity="0.25"
     inkscape:showpageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:deskcolor="#d1d1d1"
     inkscape:zoom="9.25"
     inkscape:cx="21.891892"
     inkscape:cy="28"
     inkscape:window-width="1440"
     inkscape:window-height="830"
     inkscape:window-x="-6"
     inkscape:window-y="-6"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="document" />
  <polygon
     fill="#ffffff"
     points="41,5 41,17 53,17 53,59 11,59 11,5 "
     id="polygon1"
     style="display:inline"
     transform="translate(-10,-4)" />
  <polygon
     fill="#cfd8dc"
     points="53,17 41,17 41,5 "
     id="polygon2"
     style="display:inline"
     transform="translate(-10,-4)" />
  <rect
     width="42"
     height="3"
     x="1"
     y="52"
     fill="#cfd8dc"
     id="rect2"
     style="display:inline" />
  <path
     fill="#cfd8dc"
     d="m 43,13 v 2 H 30 A 1,1 0 0 1 29,14 V 1 h 2 v 12 z"
     id="path2" />
  <path
     fill="#01579b"
     d="M 43.92,12.61 A 1,1 0 0 0 43.7,12.29 l -12,-12 A 1,1 0 0 0 31,0 H 1 A 1,1 0 0 0 0,1 v 54 a 1,1 0 0 0 1,1 h 42 a 1,1 0 0 0 1,-1 V 13 A 1,1 0 0 0 43.92,12.61 Z M 32,3.41 40.59,12 H 32 Z M 2,54 V 2 h 28 v 11 a 1,1 0 0 0 1,1 h 11 v 40 z"
     id="path3" />
  <path
     fill="#78909c"
     d="M 33,18 H 11 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,-2 h 22 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,2 z m 0,6 H 11 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,-2 h 22 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,2 z m 0,6 H 11 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,-2 h 22 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,2 z m 0,6 H 11 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,-2 h 22 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,2 z m 0,6 H 11 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,-2 h 22 a 1,1 0 0 1 0,2 z"
     id="path4" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Your example is working. But now I see the reason. The problem was because of the SVG-picture that I've downloaded from iconscout. Simple JPGs behave correct. Now its the question: what's wrong with SVG pics, why they break the line

Comment: We would need to see the actual SVG in action, to be able to answer that.

Comment: original snippet updated (without flex, same as your example)